# Is it possible to store Ubuntu updates on a server that can share them with other Ubuntu computers on the LAN?

Tags: networking, server, updates

I'm pretty sure this is possible but I have no idea what it would be called. I have several Ubuntu installations at my house (both server and desktop) and I would like to set up a server that could get all updates and then use that to update the rest of my installations without having to download the same updates from the web over and over again for each machine. It takes more time and bandwidth. What exactly is this called and what tools are available?

Comment: That beast is called _mirror_. See e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror (for local usage) or https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors (for the public).

Comment: Or a transparent squid proxy would just cache updates from the master server whenever first install happened, and others could then get served from the proxy cache.

Comment: Look at [Apt-Cacher NG](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/). I use it and once setup don't think about it any more.

Answer (score 0):

[Spacewalk](https://spacewalkproject.github.io/index.html) is Free & Open Source Systems Management Tool from which Red Hat Satellite was driven. There are workarounds to configure and manage the Ubuntu hosts as well. Check their wiki pages.